# Why can I not enable or disable views in admin/structure/views?

Tags: views, ajax

When enabling/disabling a view in the Administration/Structure/Views section I get an error:
An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 500
Debugging information follows.
Path: /?q=admin/structure/views/view/archive/preview/default/ajax
StatusText: Internal Server Error

I get a similar error when clicking Edit but I am granted access to the edit page where I can complete the task at hand.

Found a sort-of-workaround to Enable a disabled view. After clicking Enable and closing the error popup, I then clicked Edit, closed the new error popup then changed the field "Use AJAX:" to 'Yes' and Saved the changes. Lo and behold, the viewed was Enabled.

Doesn't work when attempting to Disable the view however.

Any ideas would be gratefully received.